# How can I keep Dialogflow followup intents nested when adjusting default contexts?

Tags: dialogflow-es

We're developing a system that encapsulates content through context. The context names that Dialogflow generates aren't very readable, so we've been adjusting them in the files directly.

This works for a batch of content, but when we add a new followup intent, it inherits an automatically generated context. When we adjust that context in the file directly, it dissociates with the parentID and rootParentID.

Is there a way to keep these followup intents nested in the console? It would make large volumes of content easier to manage.

Thank you.